# Checking a member to be contained in a set using from-where construct

Tags: c#

I have 1 main collection, whose member is an object with a field content-type. where value of content-type is an enum `ContentTypeEnum`.
there is a List of grouped content-type (say TEXT_GROUP or pdf, text...) `List<ContentTypeEnum>`

I want to filter result for any given content-group (TEXT_GROUP), if object's content-type is that of one in TEXT_GROUP's `List<ContentTypeEnum>`

Well I am relatively new to c#, but i have seen 'in' is there, may be that works something similar to one in sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Contains` method:

```
form p in ...
where TEXT_GROUOP.Contains(p.ContType)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Item` class:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public ContentTypeEnum Type { get; set; }
}
```

`ContentTypeEnum` enum:

```
public enum ContentTypeEnum
{
    Text,
    PDF,
    XML,
    MP3
}
```

Your group:

```
var textGroup = new List<ContentTypeEnum>() {
    ContentTypeEnum.Text,
    ContentTypeEnum.PDF,
    ContentTypeEnum.XML
};
```

Input list of `Item`:

```
var items = new List<Item>() {
    new Item() { Value = "custom PDF file", Type = ContentTypeEnum.PDF },
    new Item() { Value = "My fav MP3", Type = ContentTypeEnum.MP3 },
    new Item() { Value = "Paper", Type = ContentTypeEnum.Text }
};
```

That query will return only items, that has a type which is within `textGroup` list:

```
var textItems = items.Where(i => textGroup.Contains(i.Type)).ToList();
```

So simple `Console.WriteLine(item.Value)` for each result item will print:

```
custom PDF file
Paper
```